# Stack overflow around variable "nom"

Tags: c++

Hello i got this error after writing the second FOR inside the CONV function, each of the FORs work fine on their own but for some reason i get an overflow when i put both inside the function. Please help.

```
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
typedef struct nodo{
    char dato[100];
    struct nodo *sig;
}*pun;
typedef struct nodos{
    char nom[50];
    int num[20];
    struct nodos *sig;
}*puns;

void cargar(pun &top,pun &fin);
void mostrar(pun &top);
void conv(pun &top,pun &fin,puns &tops,puns &fins);
int main(){
    pun top=NULL,fin=NULL;
    puns tops=NULL,fins=NULL;
    cargar(top,fin);
    conv(top,fin,tops,fins);
    mostrar(top);
}

void cargar(pun &top,pun &fin){
    FILE *arch;
    pun aux=NULL;
    arch=fopen("nombres.txt","rt");
    if(arch==NULL){
        printf("No se puede abrir el archivo \n");
    }else{
        while(!feof(arch)){
            if(top==NULL){
                top=(nodo *)malloc(sizeof(nodo));
            fgets(top->dato,100,arch);
                        fin=top;
            }else{
                 aux=(nodo *)malloc(sizeof(nodo));
             fgets(aux->dato,100,arch);
             fin->sig=aux;
             fin=aux;
            }
        }
        fin->sig=NULL;
    }
```

}

```
void mostrar(pun &top){
    pun aux=top;
    while(aux!=NULL){
        puts(aux->dato);
        aux=aux->sig;
    }
}

void conv(pun &top,pun &fin,puns &tops,puns &fins){
    pun aux=top;
    puns auxs=tops;
    char nom[50],num[50],*p;
    int i,j=0,a;
    while(aux!=NULL){
        p=strchr(aux->dato,' ');
        for(i=0;i<p-aux->dato+1;i++){
             nom[i]=aux->dato[i];
        }
        nom[i]='\0';
        for(i;i<50;i++){
            num[j]=aux->dato[i];
            j++;
        }
        num[j]='\0';
        aux=aux->sig;
    }
}
```

Comment: You *sure* this is C++?

Comment: Where exactly is your problem? Can you remove unrelated parts of your code? **What have you already tried to solve this problem?** What worked and what didn't? Do you have any idea *why* your solutions didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You initilise `j` only once. You then execute this `for` loop multiple times inside the `while` loop.

```
for(i;i<50;i++){
    num[j]=aux->dato[i];
    j++;
}
```

That loop is fine the first time it is executed. For subsequent iterations of the `while` loop, `j` is off the end of `num`.

In fact, the very first time you execute `num[j]='\0'`, `j` is `50` and so you are accessing off the end of `num`.

I don't really know what your code is trying to achieve, so cannot suggest a solution. Clearly you need to avoid accessing outside the valid bounds of `num`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! adding a j=0 at the end of the function solved it.

Sorry about not being clear enough with the code, its not finished yet and this was setting me back.

Thank you again

Comment: You need to do more than that I think. You must not do `num[50]='\0'` as you do currently. And I would not be surprised if there were other out of bounds errors. You tagged this C++. If you really are using C++, the standard containers would make life a lot simpler.

Comment: There hasnt been anymore out of bound errors luckily.
Im not sure what you mean with standard containers, but what would you suggest i should do instead of num[50]='\0'?

Comment: I mean the standard C++ containers. Like `std::string`, `std::vector` and so on. You've tagged the question C++ but it looks more like you are really writing C. As for what to do instead of `num[50]='\0'`, only you know. Clearly you cannot write off the end. You could declare `num` to be of length `51`.